# Objective C IOS - int to specific string based on value of slider

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, int

So i have this slider in my view and that has a max of 13 and a min of 1.  Dependent on how you move the slider the number changes and can be shown on a label that shows the current number the slider is on.

I  want to be able to change the int from the slider into a string; so if the progress of the slider is 13 i want the label to read "A+", 12 with "A" 11 with "A-" and so on.

Without having to make 13 "if" statements because i have more than one slider, is there a way to make a method that checks the progress of the slider then converts the number to the desired letter grade?

here is my code for one of the sliders

```
-(IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    int progress = (int)roundf(slider.value);
    c1Grade.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",progress];
}
// c1Grade is the label next to the slider showing the progress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array of strings, and place the description at the index the description represents: `@"A+"` would be at index 13, `"A"` at index 12, and so on.

```
NSArray *gradeDescriptions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"", @"F", @"D-", @"D", @"D+", @"C-", @"C", @"C+", @"B-", @"B", @"B+", @"A-", @"A", @"A+", nil];
NSString *descr = [gradeDescriptions objectAt:sliderPosition];
```

Since `gradeDescriptions` array never changes, you can initialize it once, and store in a static variable or an ivar.

Comment: +1: I made a minor change to your code so that it uses values 1-13 (per the original question) instead of 0-13.  Besides, there is no such grade as F+.  :-)

Comment: @lnafziger Thanks - I guessed that there's no "F-", but I so didn't know there's no "F+"! It's a dead giveaway that I went to school that uses a different grading system :)